# How to use Customer TypeAdapter (Hive/Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart, woocommerce, flutter-hive

I'm not quite sure on how to use Hive DB in Flutter. I mean I have a ```WooCustomer```` model class and I want to store it locally (once the customer logs in).

My question is, do I have to convert that `WooCustomer` to `HiveObject` then create the `TypeAdapter` or do I create `TypeAdapter<WooCustomer>` directly?

PS: The WooCustomer is an external pkg.

Is this the correct way to implement `TypeAdapter<WooCustomer>` ?

```
class DatabaseAdapterService extends TypeAdapter<WooCustomer> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 0;

  @override
  WooCustomer read(BinaryReader reader) {
    return WooCustomer()
      ..id = reader.read()
      ..username = reader.read()
      ..firstName = reader.read()
      ..lastName = reader.read()
      ..email = reader.read()
      ..password = reader.read()
      ..avatarUrl = reader.read()
      ..role = reader.read()
      ..dateCreated = reader.read()
      ..dateCreatedGmt = reader.read()
      ..dateModified = reader.read()
      ..dateModifiedGmt = reader.read()
      ..isPayingCustomer = reader.read()
      ..links = reader.read()
      ..metaData = reader.read()
      ..billing = reader.read()
      ..shipping = reader.read();
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, WooCustomer customer) {
    writer.write(customer.username);
    writer.write(customer.id);
    writer.write(customer.firstName);
    writer.write(customer.lastName);
    writer.write(customer.email);
    writer.write(customer.password);
    writer.write(customer.links);
    writer.write(customer.avatarUrl);
    writer.write(customer.role);
    writer.write(customer.metaData);
    writer.write(customer.dateCreated);
    writer.write(customer.dateCreatedGmt);
    writer.write(customer.dateModified);
    writer.write(customer.dateModified);
    writer.write(customer.dateModifiedGmt);
    writer.write(customer.isPayingCustomer);
    writer.write(customer.billing);
    writer.write(customer.shipping);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, You can always do it.
First get these plugins, `hive, hive_flutter` in the dependencies in the pubspec.yaml.
and in the pubspec file there is also a section of `dev dependencies` there add, `hive_generator: ^1.1.0 build_runner: ^2.0.1`

And you are good to start....
First Write your Class in this Format,

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart'; //import Hive

part 'weather_model.g.dart'; 
// Specify the Location of the type-adapter's Location (specifically)
//Add the .g.dart extension
// at last of the same File name you are using
// and add "part" keyword before all.

@HiveType(typeId: 0) //Add this Line
class WeatherModel {
  @HiveField(0) //Add this Line, From Index 0... and so on.
  String user_city; // Your Class Materials...
  @HiveField(1) //Add this Line, From Index 0... and so on.
  bool celciusMetric;

  

  WeatherModel(
      {this.user_city,
      this.celciusMetric}); //Constructor here.. 

  // flutter packages pub run build_runner build
}
```

After you read the whole commented code above,
And Implemented according to your use.
Go to your Terminal and write there, `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` and you are good to go, you will find

[image: Image of Sucesss, #generated Type Adapter]

Now go to Your `main.dart` and import all the stuffs of hive.

[image: import and use Type-Adapter like this....]